# Android Studio 2.1 stable doesn't show variable values on hover for local variables

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-debug

Ever since I updated to Android Studio to version 2.1, I am unable to debug my app properly.

I can see the variable values for all class variables but I am unable to see values for method or local variables. When I do evaluate expression for a variable, I see this error **"Cannot find local variable"**

I have exhausted all the tricks mentioned in this [Issue filed on Google](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=123771).

Can someone point me in the right direction? Perhaps you might have faced this issue before...

BTW my **buildTypes** looks like this.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = false //Tried this with and without testCoverageEnabled 
        }
    }
```